# Subscribe to observable after http call. Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

this is an issue I'm having in Angular. The below method makes two http calls.

```
  submit(username: string, pword: string) {
    this.loginService.signIn(username, pword);

    this.loginService.currentloginAttemp.subscribe(data => {
      if (data == true) {
        this.profileService.getProfile();    
      }
    });

    this.profileService.newProfileObj.subscribe(dataProfile =>{
      console.log(dataProfile);
    });
  }
```

---

```
  submit(username: string, pword: string) {
    this.loginService.signIn(username, pword);
```

signIn makes an http call and assigns to an observable called currentloginAttemp

```
    this.loginService.currentloginAttemp.subscribe(data => {
      if (data == true) {
        this.profileService.getProfile();    
      }
    });
```

The above code works without any problems. this.profileService.getProfile() makes an http call to obtain a new Profile. The below code subscribes to that profile that was obtained.

```
    this.profileService.newProfileObj.subscribe(dataProfile =>{
      console.log(dataProfile);
    });
  }
```

When I do console.log(dataProfile); I get an undefined warning.

When I run this function:

```
  logout() {
        this.profileService.newProfileObj.subscribe(dataProfile =>{
          console.log(dataProfile);
        });
  }
```

console.log(dataProfile) returns a profile.

How do I delay after the line of code **this.profileService.getProfile()** so that when I subscribe to the profile, my component will see it?

EDIT:

Just to be clear. currentloginAttemp is assigned when this.loginService.signIn makes an http call. Which is why I'm not sure why newProfileObj is null when it is assigned in the method this.profileService.getProfile().

EDIT 2:

```
  getProfile() {
    let tempURL = this.getProfileUrl + this.currProfileId.value;
    this.http.get<Profile>(tempURL).subscribe((data) => {
      this.currProfileObj.next(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you post a testable code on stackbitz so we can test it

Comment: JD333 - did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using a BehaviorSubject and it is emitting immediately, as well as each time you issue .next().  See docs on how BehaviorSubject works [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject).  Because of this, you'll often want to skip that first emission because you really only care about the rest of them.  In your case that would look something like this (in rxjs 6+):

```
this.profileService.newProfileObj.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(dataProfile =>{
  console.log(dataProfile);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution. But, I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

Inside my component I created a function:

```
  async delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
  }
```

After making the second http call I called the async functino from above ^:

```
    (async () => { 
      // Do something before delay
      console.log('before delay')

     await this.delay(2000);
      this.profileService.newProfileObj.subscribe(dataProfile =>{
        console.log(dataProfile);
      // Do something after
      console.log('after delay')
  })();
```

This worked, although I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

Comment: How may I do this? I'd like to use the most minimal delay. But, exactly what happens if the network is too slow. I can set a dynamic delay that know whether or not the network is slow.

Comment: can you post a minimal demo on stackbitz so we can find exactly what's the issue.your solution wont work if response come after the delay.so it's not a good solution

Comment: See the solution I proposed - it is better than this one since it waits for the event regardless of when it occurs rather than trying to time it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using subject. You should use BehaviorSubject instead of subject. A subject doesn't hold a value.

Subject example:

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();
subject.next(1);
subject.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Console output will be empty

BehaviorSubject example:

```
const subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject();
subject.next(1);
subject.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Console output: 1

BehaviorSubject can be created with initial value: new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1)

You can also try this if you don't want to use above method.

```
 this.profileService.newProfileObj.subscribe(dataProfile =>{
        if (dataProfile) {
            console.log(dataProfile);
          }   
        });
  }
```

Comment: I am using Behavior Subject

Comment: @JD333 please show your getProfile function. this seems subject issue to me. you may have created a different instance of your service

Comment: Just posted it now

Comment: @JD333 i mean newProfileObj declaration code. why you have currProfileObj in get profile and you have subscribed to newProfileObj. why have you used different name for same subject

Comment: currProfileObj is the Subject. newProfileObj is the observable.

Comment: @JD333 there is some synchronization issue in your code. Please share a minimal demo on stackbitz.

Answer (score -1):

```
getxTaskXCall()
     getxTask()
      .subscribe(
        success => {
         processFn(success);
        },
        error => {
          // this.errors = error;
        },
        () => {

        }
      );
       getxTask(tId: string, parameters: Array<number>): Observable<[string]> {
        return this.apiService.get(getUrl + tId + '/' + parameters)
            .pipe(map(data => data));
    }

 get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${api_url}${path}`, { params })
      .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }
```